# Swing: JFileChooser with favorites?

Tags: swing, jfilechooser, favorites

I'm working on an application which needs to select files. [JFileChooser](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) is a great start, but I need to augment it. I can start it at one particular directory with `JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory()`, but how can I offer the user a "favorites" functionality, either in terms of favorite files saved for later, or favorite directories to jump to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the JFileChooser accessory was intended to be used for things like thumbnails of the currently selected file, per [the JavaDocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAccessory%28javax.swing.JComponent%29):

> An accessory is often used to show a
>   preview image of the selected file;
>   however, it can be used for anything
>   that the programmer wishes, such as
>   extra custom file chooser controls.

So you'll have to create a custom JComponent to represent "favorite directories", then call `setAccessory(myFavesComponent)` on your file chooser.

To actually implement the storage of favorite directories, you'll want to use the [Preferences API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are already some libraries in Java of "favorites" feature, you can use, for example, this [one](https://github.com/fracpete/jfilechooser-bookmarks).